# How to install apt-get or YUM on Mac OS X

Tags: osx, package-management

I want to use either of `apt-get` or `yum`.

How to install them and make them successful running?

Comment: Why do you want to install them? What software do you want to install that you expect to find as .deb or .rpm files which will work on an OS X install?

Comment: Both utilities are too Linux-specific (and/or too Fedora/Debian-specific) so they won't work on OSX without serious effort on your part,so Michael's question stands: what exactly is it you want to do?

Comment: obviously OP is asking about the equivalent -- seriously...

Comment: By the way, for installing SDKs (software development kits) such as Java JDK on macOS, I suggest using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), a slick set of shell scripts.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you want the equivalent of apt-get or yum on Mac OS X, you have two choices.

1. Homebrew: http://brew.sh
2. Macports: http://www.macports.org

You can use `brew install PACKAGE_NAME` or `port install PACKAGE_NAME` to install the package available.

Comment: There are guides on how to run Hombrew side-by-side with Macports or Fink, but it is generally recommended to choose one and stick with it. Homebrew is pretty much the standard these days. There is only a single instance I can recall personally, where a package I needed was available via Macports and not Homebrew, and that was an X11-based GUI browser -- Firefox, I believe, which would have been really nice to browse with over SSH in some specific localhost scenario I was working with at the time. It's just a personal preference thing, mostly. Homebrew is the best and most user-friendly, IMHO.

Comment: what is the exact syntax to install apt-get ? brew install apt-get gives "Error: No available formula with the name "apt-get"

Comment: @Daniele idea here is brew install would be the equivalent of apt-get and not use apt-get through brew.

Comment: @rubynorails you mentioned guides for installing homebrew side-by-side with Fink. Can you link me to one? I'm having trouble locating one

Comment: @kraftydevil It has been 4 years since I posted this, and `brew` has become pretty much the standard as far as package managers go for MacOS. However, if you know how both package managers work and where all of the files live, I believe it should still be possible. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889841](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889841)

Answer (score 11):

You need to install either Homebrew or YUM. To install Homebrew enter the following command in terminal.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

then use brew install *Package_name*

Comment: Does `ruby` come pre-installed with each OSX?

Comment: @Anthon: Yes, for several years now.

Comment: Thanks for including the command line download for HomeBrew. Beautiful.

Comment: Actually the official brew site recommends the following command for Mac and Linux. Consider updating the answer: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to use apt-get on OS X 10.9 like Deb based Linux using a third party software named Fink - [How to Install apt-get on Mac OS X](http://thecustomizewindows.com/2013/11/how-to-install-apt-get-on-mac-os-x/). However, unlike Homebrew and OS X Package Managers, Fink does not use /usr/local/ path to install software. It simply means, Fink is for a bit advanced users who can handle the software conflicts (for difference in version).
Homebrew, to me is the best package manager...

Comment: This is the correct answer if one wants to run apt and use Debian packages on the Mac.

Answer (score 4):

#### Installing Homebrew

Open terminal and type:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)" `
```

#### Using Homebrew

Open terminal and do one of the following:

- Installing casks (applications)

  ```
  brew cask install PKG
  ```
- Installing kegs (command line tools and other packages)

  ```
  brew install PKG
  ```
- Uninstalling kegs or casks (any packages)

  ```
  brew uninstall PKG
  ```
- Uninstalling all kegs installed with homebrew

  ```
  brew uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/*
  ```
- Searching for a package

  ```
  brew search PKG
  ```
- List installed packages

  ```
  brew list
  ```
- Replace PKG with the name of the package.

#### Uninstalling Homebrew

- Big Sur, Catalina, and Mojave:
  Open terminal and type:

  ```
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
  ```
- High Sierra, and earlier
  Open terminal and type:

  ```
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
  ```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

These are some other way

visit https://sdkman.io/

```
# you can use sdk install command to install software
$ sdk install package_name
```

examples:

```
MacdeMacBook-Pro$ sdk install java 8.0.191-oracle

Oracle requires that you agree with the Oracle Binary Code License Agreement
prior to installation. The license agreement can be found at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Do you agree to the terms of this agreement? (Y/n): Y

Downloading: java 8.0.191-oracle

In progress...
########################## 100.0%
We will be needing super powers...
Password:

Repackaging Java 8u191...
Attaching to the DMG...
Mounting DMG as Volume...
Volume(s) mounted successfully
Installing PKG inside DMG...
installer: Package name is JDK 8 Update 191
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
Copy JDK Home to temp folder...
Preparing archive...
Unmounting volume...
"/Volumes/JDK 8 Update 191" unmounted successfully.
Done repackaging...
Cleaning up cookie...

Installing: java 8.0.191-oracle
Done installing!

Setting java 8.0.191-oracle as default.
MacdeMacBook-Pro:Homebrew mac$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew and MacPorts are the better known alternatives, so i wont spend time on those here aswell.

I am a heavy Fedora/Centos user who recently had to learn how to get Mac os to behave as much as Linux as possible. I think the best package manager i have found is pkgsrc: available here https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/

Pkgsrc has some 20000 packages, 4x HomeBrew - give it a go :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you can use brew or macports on MacOS

- '[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)' - The Missing Package Manager for macOS (or Linux)
- '[Macports](https://www.macports.org/)' - https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports

**To Install Homebrew**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**Using Homebrew commands:**

Open terminal and do one of the following:

Installing casks (applications)

```
brew cask install <package>
```

Installing kegs (command line tools and other packages)

```
brew install <package>
```

Uninstalling kegs or casks (any packages)

```
brew uninstall <package>
```

Answer (score -1):

## install pkg

$ sdk install   or i     [version]

## uninstall pkg

$ sdk uninstall or rm

## list avaliable pkg

$ sdk list      or ls   [candidate]
#
$ sdk use       or u     [version]
$ sdk default   or d     [version]
$ sdk current   or c    [candidate]
$ sdk upgrade   or ug   [candidate]

## show current version of sdk manager

$ sdk version   or v
$ sdk broadcast or b
$ sdk help      or h
$ sdk offline           [enable|disable]
$ sdk selfupdate        [force]
$ sdk update
$ sdk flush

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question is specifically about getting APT or YUM working on OS X, not about the general usage of `sdk`.

Comment: I agree with @TooTea. This makes no effort to answer the specific question.