# Error when using apt on macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, apt, macintosh

Having some trouble using apt on my Mac. If I run `sudo apt search` or `sudo apt-get` I get this error in the terminal:

`Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)`

I am running Sierra 10.12.4 and am trying to use the `md5sum` command on Mac.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: When did Mac start supporting apt ?  The apt utils are from Debian Linux.

Comment: I am not really sure, they may not, I just don't ever use things like that in terminal on the Mac. If I use the terminal I usually use Ubuntu, was just trying to get `md5sum` to word on Mac @ivanivan

Comment: If this seems like a rookie mistake, I assure you it's not. I type sudo apt install all the dang time on my Mac, in spite of having used MacPorts for probably 10 years and Debian for even longer. Too bad `/usr/bin/apt` is apparently protected by [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), otherwise I'd probably just remove it to save the aggravation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt`, the package manager, is a Linux tool, from Debian GNU/Linux.  macOS does not have it. The `apt` program that happens to be in your search path is Java's [annotation processing tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/), and will not do what you want.

There are projects like Homebrew, MacPorts and Fink that provides packaged third-party software for macOS.

- Homebrew: https://brew.sh/
- MacPorts: https://www.macports.org/
- Fink: http://www.finkproject.org/

NetBSD's pkgsrc also works nicely on macOS:  http://www.pkgsrc.org/

As for `md5sum`: On the BSD Unices, of which macOS is one, there is often a utility called `md5` available that performs the same service (but with slightly different format of output).

If you install GNU coreutils using the tools provided by one of the above projects, `md5sum` will be installed. The executable is sometimes called `gmd5sum` (note the added `g` prefix, which also gets added to all other GNU coreutils executables).

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, I think that I am going to have a look into Homebrew for the future, but have just read the manual for `md5`, does the job I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

macOS doesn’t use the APT package management tools, at least not by default. Here you’re ending up trying to run Java’s [annotation processing tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/).

If you want to check out package management tools on macOS, see [How to install apt-get or YUM on Mac OS X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80711/86440); Fink allows you to install `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what `/usr/bin/apt` _actually_ is on macOS. Do you know if that's there for a "factory" Mac installation, or does installing the Java JRE or whatever put it there?

Comment: @TheDudeAbides I’m afraid I don’t know, and I don’t have a current Mac handy, so I can’t check either.

Comment: I wasn't able to `sudo rm /usr/bin/apt`, presumably because of [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), so I guess it's part of the factory install.